# Emacs in terminal mode and line wrap

Tags: emacs, gnu

Why does emacs display a "\" when a line wraps? Visually this is no issue, but if I want to copy a line which also wraps, the "\" character is also copied to the clipboard. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: What platform and emacs version are you using?

Comment: I am using RHEL5 and tsch.

Comment: @David I am using emacs 21.3.1

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using emacs in a terminal.  In that case the `\` is the way emacs tells you that the same line continues in a portion of the emacs "Frame" called the "fringes".  Try `M-x customize-option RET fringe-mode RET`, set it to `No fringes`, then click the `State` button and select `Save for future sessions`.

Comment: I dont have "fringe-mode" in my emacs 21.3.1.

Comment: Then you'll have to figure out how to get rid of the fringes on your version.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to your .emacs file:

```
(set-display-table-slot standard-display-table 'wrap ?\ )
```